The enqueue_block_assets is changing the styles of the editor interface
I am ensuing stylesheets that are supposed to be used by a theme in the iframe from the editor and on the front end. Some of the css contains styles for html tags such as H1, H2 etc..
body {
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 30px;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 20px;
}

etc..

Whilst the styles are correctly applied to the content in the iFrame and on the front end, this css is also overriding interface elements of the admin editor.
The only way I can find around this is to wrap everything with body:not(.wp-admin) however this causes issues further down the line where additional stylesheets also need to use this deflation when overriding the same html tag style.
Is there a way around this. I enqueue like this:
    add_action('enqueue_block_assets', function (){
      wp_enqueue_style(
        'my-core-style-overrides',
        'path/to/my-core-style-overrides.css',
        ver: 1
      ); 
    });


The trouble is that they 'enqueue_block_assets' is not the right hook to use for conditional resources anyway. The correct hook to use for the backend is :
add_editor_style( 'path/to/my-core-style-overrides.css'), which should be inside 'after_setup_theme' hook.
This will ensure that these styles are incorporated in the admin editor iframe only and in all places where that iframe can exists such as when editing the theme via wp_enqueue_style hook. This hook can now be contained in wp_enqueue_scripts to ensure it is frontend only.
A bit of a mess I know but a correct implementation.
The original reason for this question was due to a plugin I wrote for conditionally adding resources to a post or page. Whilst this can be done it will not function correctly on the backend anyway without a page reload every time a resource is added. Therefore all resources should be added to the backend and conditional resources added conditionally using login on the front end.
